# How to compute the variances in Expectation Maximization with n dimensions?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, expectation-maximization

I have been reviewing Expectation Maximization (EM) in research papers such as this one:

http://pdf.aminer.org/000/221/588/fuzzy_k_means_clustering_with_crisp_regions.pdf

I have some doubts that I have not figured it out. For example, what would happen if we have many dimensions for each datapoint?

For example I have the following dataset with 6 datapoints and 4 dimensions:

```
>D1 D2 D3  D4   
5, 19, 72, 5  
6, 18, 14, 1  
7, 22, 29, 4   
3, 22, 51, 1   
2, 21, 89, 2   
1, 12, 28, 1
```

It means that for computing the expectation step, do I need to compute 4 standard deviations (one for each dimension)?

Do I also have to compute the variance for each cluster assuming k=3 (Do not know if it is necessary based on the formula from the paper...) or just the variances for each dimensions (4 attributes)?

Comment: EM is a tool, not a goal by itself.  In order to apply it to some problem you first have to state the problem you want to solve.  Given just your data many different problems can be constructed, with different answers to your questions.

Comment: Hello Pentadecagon, thanks! I know that EM is a technique and well there are so many papers with so different implementations of the algorithm :(... but I was wondering if there are some problems where I only have to compute different sigma for each dimension or compute sigmas for each cluster?
In the paper about EM they only state that sigma is chosen randomly and they are only showing one dimension for the datapoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you use a [Covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix), which also includes variances.

But it really depends on your chosen model. The simplest model does not use variances at all.
A more complex model has a single variance value, the average variance over all dimensions.
Next, you can have a separate variance for each dimension independently; and last but not least a full covariance matrix. That is probably the most flexible GMM in popular use.

Depending on your implementation, there can be many more.

From R's mclust documentation:

#### univariate mixture

"E"     =   equal variance (one-dimensional)
"V"     =   variable variance (one-dimensional)

#### multivariate mixture

"EII"   =   spherical, equal volume
"VII"   =   spherical, unequal volume
"EEI"   =   diagonal, equal volume and shape
"VEI"   =   diagonal, varying volume, equal shape
"EVI"   =   diagonal, equal volume, varying shape
"VVI"   =   diagonal, varying volume and shape
"EEE"   =   ellipsoidal, equal volume, shape, and orientation
"EEV"   =   ellipsoidal, equal volume and equal shape
"VEV"   =   ellipsoidal, equal shape
"VVV"   =   ellipsoidal, varying volume, shape, and orientation

#### single component

"X"     =   univariate normal
"XII"   =   spherical multivariate normal
"XXI"   =   diagonal multivariate normal
"XXX"   =   elliposidal multivariate normal

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse!

Actually, I want to program the algorithm from the paper I posted of EM, that is the same from the udacity course: 
https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud741/l-644878538/m-638188664

At the moment I am computing an average variance for each dimension, in my example 4... 

My question is by following that implementation, should I compute the Variance for each dimension (4 sigmas) and also compute the sigma for each cluster?

Comment: I am not using a covariance matrix since I am assuming all dimensions are independen